# Flag manifolds as homogeneous Kahler manifolds

Tags: lie-groups, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, homogeneous-spaces, flag-varieties

In this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45004/kahler-structure-on-flag-manifolds) it is asked if every flag manifold can be given the structure of a Kähler manifold. In the first answer it is written

> Flag manifolds exhaust all compact homogeneous Kähler manifolds corresponding to a compact connected semi-simple Lie group

What is the standard reference for this result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flag manifolds $G/C(S)$ even exhaust homogeneous *symplectic* manifolds of $G$: Borel-Weil ([1954](//zbmath.org/?q=an:0121.16203), Thm 1). Also restated with fewer details in ([1954](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0058.16002), Thm 1).

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused by "even homogeneous symplectic". Every symplectic manifold is automatically even dimensional - is there some meaning to "odd dimensional homogeneous symplectic"?

Comment: Better now? (“even” = adverb qualifying exhaust, not adjective qualifying manifolds.)

Comment: Ah, I see :) Thanks for clearing this up!